# How to implement REGEXP in foreach the right way?

Tags: php, sql

**Hello,
How to add regexp the right way in this code in order to search for exact word in database?**

```html
$condition = '';
$name = "he  is mad";
$query = explode(" ", $name);
foreach($query as $text) {
    $condition .= "test LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $text)."%' OR ";
}

$condition = rtrim($condition, " OR ");

$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE " . $condition;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "1";
} else {
    echo "0";
}
$conn->close();
```

**I want to add this to the php code**

```html
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    Description regexp '(^|[[:space:]])pen([[:space:]]|$)';
```

**It only works with me like this without foreach:**

```html
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE test regexp '(^|[[:space:]])$condition([[:space:]]|$)'";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the last " OR " from your $condition

```
<?php
$condition = '';
$name = "Hello world i am so sad";
$query = explode(" ", $name);
foreach($query as $text) {
    $condition .= "test LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $text)."%' OR ";
}
// HERE REMOVE LAST " OR " FROM STRING
$condition = rtrim($condition, " OR ");

$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE " . $condition;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "1";
} else {
    echo "0";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: It still check for "d" letter and return found as it matched "sad".
when check for "d" it should return false!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a phrase that is separated by spaces and you want to see if there is any overlap with the words, you can possibly use regular expressions:

```
where col regexp replace($name, ' ', '|')
```

Note that you should be passing `$name` in as a parameter.

If you care about word boundaries, you can introduce them into the regular expression.  However, the exact form may depend on which regular expression library MySQL is using.  The idea is:

```
where col regexp concat('\\b', replace($name, ' ', '\\b|\\b'), '\\b')
```

Comment: It is not working. Check my update. After update it works but it matches letter d with sad in database and return true ?!

Comment: @JavaDava . . . That is a question of word boundaries, which you can incorporate into the regular expression.

Comment: Can you help me do the following update of my post?